# ext4 filesystem damaged with strange "Not a directory" messages?

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext4

It's strange but after filesystem damage some folders/directories are now shown as files instead of directories ?

I would be very grateful if someone was able to help me to correct the filesystem and/or try to find where the files are, now ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help !

Answer (score 2):

You fsck the thing, and then restore from backup if that doesn't fix things.  You *could* use `debugfs` to modify the filesystem to make things directories again, but quite honestly you'll spend far longer hunting down every problem and fixing it (and how will you get an exhaustive list of everything that's actually broken?) than you will just restoring from backup.  That's assuming that the damage is limited to flipping mode bits; if there's actual file corruption, all bets are off.

Comment: In fact I restored everything from backups to a new server, but backups were one day old. The two folder that now look like files are the two database (mysql & postgresql) folder and I would be happy to find out what was inside just in case, but if I understand correctly, you think that the chances to find something useful are low ?

Comment: It depends on the exact nature of the corruption, but mode bits don't normally get flipped without something else going on.